# Take advantage of the same attributes in a class

Tags: python, class

In this class here:

```
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, Type, name):
        self.Type = Type
        self.name = name
        self.atk = 'Undefined'

        if Type == 'Paladin':
            self.hp = 150
            self.dmg = [10, 20]
            self.atk = random.randint(self.dmg[0], self.dmg[1])
            self.defence = 25
            self.dodge = 5

        elif Type == 'Mage':
            self.hp = 70
            self.dmg = [60, 70]
            self.atk = random.randint(self.dmg[0], self.dmg[1])
            self.defence = 15
            self.dodge = 8

        elif Type == 'Archer':
            self.hp = 100
            self.dmg = [40, 50]
            self.atk = random.randint(self.dmg[0], self.dmg[1])
            self.defence = 10
            self.dodge = 13
```

I'm noticing that I always have hp, dmg, atk, defence, dodge for each if statement. Since python is OOP, is there a way to take advantage if that and not need to write all of these things manually?

Comment: You could make the types be subclasses, that would be paradigmatic use of OOP. (Not that it reduces the amount of lines of code you have.) You could also make a class HeroStats, pass an instance of it to the constructor and assign it. This is, however, not good OOP style (cumbersome to extend for example), although it potentially reduces the amount of typing you end up doing, assuming you have very many types and lots of stats.

Comment: delegation pattern aka class inheritance

Comment: You could turn `self.atk = random.randint(self.dmg[0], self.dmg[1])` into a private method like `_set_atk` to save a tiny bit of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `inheritance` and create 3 subclasses of your `Hero` class to move the code.

The `Hero` class where you can write an util method to create different types of Hero

```
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, Type, name):
        self.name = name
        self.atk = 'Undefined'

    def _init_atk(self):
        self.atk = random.randint(self.dmg[0], self.dmg[1])

    @staticmethod
    def get_hero(hero_type, name):
        if hero_type == 'Paladin':
          return Paladin(name)
        elif hero_type == 'Mage':
          return Mage(name)
        elif hero_type == 'Archer':
          return Archer(name)
        return None
```

The heroes classes, that defined their own value of the attributs

```
class Paladin(Hero):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super(Paladin, self).__init(name)
        self.hp = 150
        self.dmg = [10, 20]
        self.defence = 25
        self.dodge = 5
        self._init_atk()

class Mage(Hero):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super(Mage, self).__init(name)
        self.hp = 70
        self.dmg = [60, 70]
        self.defence = 15
        self.dodge = 8
        self._init_atk()

class Archer(Hero):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super(Archer, self).__init(name)
        self.hp = 100
        self.dmg = [40, 50]
        self.defence = 10
        self.dodge = 13
        self._init_atk()
```

Then you can create object like

```
a = Archer("RobinHood")
b = Hero.get_hero("Mage", "HarryPotter")
```

Comment: Why do you have `Hero.get_hero`? I mean, initializing a child class from a parent class seems strange. As well it gets inherited, so `b = Archer.get_hero("Mage", "HarryPotter")` would work, which also seems strange.

Comment: @wjandrea just to keep it's way to craete object using `the condition, this is removable ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance to derive various `Hero Characters` from a superclass and give each new type a specific set of values; you can also give them specific attributes, and behaviors:

Using class variables to store the values simplifies the code:

```
from abc import ABC
import random


class Hero(ABC):   # this cannot be instantiated 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.atk = random.randint(self.dmg[0], self.dmg[1])
        self.hp = self.__class__.hp
        self.dmg = list(self.__class__.dmg)
        self.defence = self.__class__.defence
        self.dodge = self.__class__.dodge
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__qualname__}: {self.name}, atk: {self.atk}, hp: {self.hp}, dmg: {self.dmg}, defense: {self.defence}, dodge: {self.dodge}'


class Paladin(Hero):
    hp = 150
    dmg = (10, 20)
    defence = 25
    dodge = 5
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)


class Mage(Hero):
    hp = 70
    dmg = (60, 70)
    defence = 15
    dodge = 8
    def __init__(self, name, spells):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.spells = spells[:]
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{super().__str__()}\n\tspells: {self.spells}'


class Archer(Hero):
    hp = 100
    dmg = (40, 50)
    defence = 10
    dodge = 13
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)


A = Archer('Guillaume Tell')
B = Mage('Gandalf', ['quadratus lumborum', 'rectus femoris'])
C = Paladin('Ali Baba')

print(A)
print(B)
print(C)
```

## Output:

```
Archer: Guillaume Tell, atk: 49, hp: 100, dmg: [40, 50], defense: 10, dodge: 13
Mage: Gandalf, atk: 62, hp: 70, dmg: [60, 70], defense: 15, dodge: 8
    spells: ['quadratus lumborum', 'rectus femoris']
Paladin: Ali Baba, atk: 13, hp: 150, dmg: [10, 20], defense: 25, dodge: 5
```